# Mysql query, select join two table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a LIKE table and a BOOK table and my user_id.

I want to pull only i have liked from BOOK table with BOOK NAMES and AUTHOR

My json will:

```
{book_id:1,bookname:sample,author:sean,user_id:111}
```

tables

```
-----------BOOK TABLE------------
ID ---- BOOK AUTHOR ---- BOOK NAME

1
2

...................................


USERS TABLE
ID-------NAME
1
2
.............

LIKE TABLE---------------------------
ID-----BOOK ID-------LIKER USER ID---
1
2
.....................................
```

Comment: site note: If it's not too late I'd consider renaming the like table.  Using reserved words as table names gets annoying over time.

Answer (score 0):

For getting all the data related to likes you can run this sql command.
The result set you can loop and generate the JSON.
Make sure in the query you have all your column names correctly given.

```
select 
b.book_id,
b.bookname,
b.author,
u.user_id
from 
`like` l
inner join book b on b.book_id = l.book_id
inner join users u on u.user_id = l.user_id
```

If you need to filter data just add a where condition after the last JOIN as

```
where u.user_id = {your user id}
```

Comment: where should i put $user_id?

Comment: "inner join users u on u.user = l.user_id" -> did you mean u.user_id = l.user_id?

Comment: why i cant get repeated value-key pair?

Comment: check your loop if you are over-writing the array. Also try the query first on mysql and see what you are getting.

Comment: it is not gving true results,i need 'users liked book names and book ids. that all

Comment: post some data along with tables on sqlfiddle.com so that it could be checked there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT book.*, users.*, like.* FROM like INNER JOIN
                          users ON like.liker_user_id = users.id INNER JOIN
                          book ON like.book_id = book.id WHERE
                          users.id = ?
                         ");
$stmt->bind_param( "d", $user_id); 

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($col1);
// then fetch and close the statement
```